# Jquery Datatable Excel export value got changed in downloaded file

Tags: jquery, excel, datatables

i was using Jquery Datatable to export the file. but after downloading the number format got changed in excel file.

My code is :

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.27/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


         $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'excel'
        ]
    } );


    });
</script>
```

**Table Output is:**

[image]

**Excel Output is:**

[image]

From above output the field **SerialNumber** is getting changed. i need same output which is in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is larger than Javascript supports.  The largest integer is 9007199254740991.  This is discussed [Javascript Number doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).  This DT [thread](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/102834/#Comment_102834) also discusses this topic.